# Is extending Bartik a recommended move?

Tags: 8

I'm starting a new Drupal 8 project. As first steps I need to choose a theme. So far, I have only experience with Bario, chosen initially for using Bootstrap 4. I'm now looking for a theme that's not using Bootstrap.

I'm considering extending Bartik. Is this correct, or should I extend a different theme?

Comment: This comment will likely get shut down, as this is a question-and-answer site, and the answer to your question is primarily opinion-based. You may want to re-post it on Drupal.org, where it won't get shut down.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Unfortunately. which theme to use for a site is quite subjective. The only question that isn't subjective is the one asking about extending Bartik. (You are also asking many questions in a single post, which is something that should be avoided. There is also a closing reason for questions not asking a single question.)

Comment: Basically, I would like to know what is the convention in these situation, not what is the prettiest theme. What's the lightest ones, is it recommended to extend Bartik and what happened to classy because it's not clear. Thank you.

Comment: We cannot tell you which one is the lightest one, and probably that is a subjective criterium. It is surely a criterium that changes over time because new themes are created, and existing themes are changed. You are also asking 4 different questions; I would rather keep _I'm considering extending Bartik. Is this a recommended move?_ which is answerable, and remove the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Drupal core themes no longer extend Classy](https://www.drupal.org/node/3103178) change record.

> Bartik, Claro, Seven, and Umami are part of the product rather than
>   the API and therefore it is not officially supported to extend them.
>   These themes can change as part of a minor release and cause
>   regressions to any themes extending them.

Means: No it's not recommended to extend Bartik. Extend Classy or Stable instead.